# Fetch Delete Request not working Properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, fetch

With the Fetch API I am sending the following request:

```
const target = e.currentTarget;
fetch(target.href, {
  method: 'delete',
})
.then(res => console.log(22))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Also, this is the middleware that handles this request:

```
exports.deleteImageById = async (req, res) => {
 const image_id = req.params.image_id;
  const imagePromise = Image.findByIdAndRemove(image_id);
  const commentPromise = Comment.remove( {image_id} );
  await Promise.all([imagePromise, commentPromise])
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  req.flash('Image Deleted!');
  // return something well!
  res.status(200);
};
```

The document is being deleted but the `then` block in the fetch statement does not work. It does not output anything to the console.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is not being received and therefore the `then` will not be called.  In the server change

```
res.status(200);
```

to include `end()` since [status](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status) does not send the response

```
res.status(200).end();
```

or [sendStatus](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendStatus)

```
res.sendStatus(200);
```

Comment: `req.flash` isn't working if I use `window.location.href = '/'`. Do I have to create the flash on the client side?

Comment: I'm not sure. it looks like flash is used before redirects.  You could ask another question about flash itself!

Answer (score 1):

`res.status` is only used to set the status code it does not send the response.

Instead use the following:

`res.sendStatus(200)`